# Router fluctuates in speed rapidly: how to diagnose?

Tags: wireless-networking, internet, wireless-router

I'm having a very interesting problem with my router and was wondering how I might go about diagnosing (and ultimately fixing) the problem.

(All cited numbers are through [SPEEDTEST](http://www.speedtest.net/).)

I live in an apartment with thick walls and the router is in the living room. We pay for 100 Mbps, and when I connect my laptop to the router through ethernet (the connection looks like: ISP --> modem --> router --> laptop), I do in fact get about 100 Mbps.

From my bedroom, however, the speed fluctuates with high frequency. For example, just today, a speed test at 1:00 pm resulted in 40 Mbps (what I usually get), and another speed test at 1:02 pm resulted in <1 Mbps.

I conjectured that this might be because of thick walls and interference and the like, but I did the tests again with my laptop *right next* to the router. At 1:10 pm I got 60 Mbps, and at 1:12 pm I got <5 Mbps.

Finally, I downloaded a WiFi analyzer app and found that the signal strength is about -55 dBm from my room and -40 dBm right next to the router. This difference is expected.

This fluctuation poses a problem when watching live streams, since the times the connection speed is low, I can't load the video frames quickly enough.

I'm looking for a way to diagnose whether this a problem with my laptop, with the router/model, or with the ISP itself. This problem occurred about two months ago, disappeared for that period of time, and just cropped back up now. It might go away by itself again, but being proactive about fixing it might be helpful.

Is there any easy way to figure out the problem?

---

Specs:

- Laptop: Lenovo Z580 (2.4 GHz)
- ISP: Comcast
- Router: Netgear AC1200

Comment: Well you already identified the issue to be in your apartment since a direct connection works fine.  So now you're in one of those ultra common cases of wifi speed issues.  The fact that your walls are tick is apparently not making a difference.

Comment: What speed and frequency band is your laptop connecting at?

Comment: I'm not sure what speed means in this case, but my laptop is old so it's using the 2.4 GHz channel. I have my router set to automatically change channels within this band to avoid interference.

Comment: Look at the connection details for the speed it's actually connected, which could fluctuate.  Note that automatic channel selection is never done live and only happens when the router is restarted.